# Sendmail.php webform sending blank emails

Tags: java, php, email, webforms

Ok so I am a bit of a noob when it comes to all this... However I am now at breaking point after trying to get this to function for nearly 10 hours today, everything I have tried seems to fail, so any advice would really be appreciated.

The emails are sending ok, however on arrival they show only:

*Name:*

*Surname:*

*Email:*

*Message:*

I haven't been able to get anything other than this to come through.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST[‘surname’];
$email = $_POST[‘email’];  
$message = $_POST[‘message’];
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'admin@park.co.uk';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Surname: ' . $surname . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

The Main JS coding is as follows:

```
   //contact form
    var form = $(‘.contact-form’);
    form.submit(function () {
$this = $(this);
$.post($(this).attr(‘action’),$(‘.contact-form’).serialize(), function(data) {
$this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
$this.closest(‘.contact-form’).find(“input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea”).val(“”);
},’json’);
return false;
});
//goto top
$(‘.gototop’).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(‘html, body’).animate({
scrollTop: $(“body”).offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

And the HTML code is:

```
<h4>Contact Form</h4>
      <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form"

        method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" required="required"

                placeholder="Name" type="text"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" required="required"

                placeholder="Surname" type="text"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" required="required"

                placeholder="Email" type="text"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send
                Message</button> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7"> <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required"

              class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <input name="subject" value="Form submission" type="hidden"> </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

If anyone can help me get this working I would really appreciate it, as would my sanity!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your inputs don't have name properties

Comment: you probably want to remove your real email to save it from getting spammed

Comment: I notice a lot of your single quotes `'` are special characters that MS Word typically inserts. Make sure you're using a proper single quote

Comment: As @DelightedD0D writed, you have to add `name` attribute to form inputs, since `.serialize()` use them, otherwise they will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will have a look...

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to pinpoint what is causing the issue for you but there are several problems, including;

- Your inputs don't have name attribute which are needed for `serialize()` to do it's job
- as @Machavity points out, you have some curly quotes in your code that should be be straight quotes
- Your php page will echo that an email was successfully sent regardless of what happens

---

It it were me, I would use ajax for this and here's how:

### Full working example found [here](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/emailtest/)

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Contact Form</h4>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email to send to.. (Added for the demo)" name="to" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
            <input name="subject" value="Form submission" type="hidden">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {  
    //contact form
    $('#main-contact-form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the normal form submission
        var sendVars = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendemail.php",
            data: sendVars,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // do stuff...
                console.log(data);
                $('#data').text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                $('#main-contact-form').find('input, textarea').val('');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
          }
        });
    });
    //goto top
    $('.gototop').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors',1);  //error reporting if needed
//ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
//error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array( 'fail'=>array('type'=>'failure',
                       'message'=>'Email Failed!'),
                 'succeed'=>array('type'=>'success',
                       'message'=>'Email Sent!'));

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']): null;
$surname = isset($_POST['surname']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']): null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']): null;  
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']): null;
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = isset($_POST['message']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['to']): null;

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Surname: ' . $surname . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

if(mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>')){
    echo json_encode($status['succeed']);
    die;
    
}
else{
    echo json_encode($status['fail']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, working perfectly, just need to tweak it now.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Dont forget to mark your question as answered : )